# Why authentication is bypass

Tags: android, codeigniter, okhttp

i make application android connect with codeigniter, but why i am entered wrong username and password, authentication is not working. Just like its bypassed to MainActivity.class, please tell me whats wrong?

This is my code:

```
public void onClick(View view){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("username_kirim", username.getText().toString())
                .add("password_kirim", password.getText().toString())
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url_login).post(formBody).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                throw new IOException("Gagal Terkoneksi" + response);
            }
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                if(checkFlag){
                    editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                }
                Intent loged = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(loged);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't set the StrictModePolicy.  What you're doing is a hack that won't work on many devices and that causes a bad experience for your user.  Learn how to use an AsyncTask for networking, or use a networking library.

Comment: yes i will change it after, this problem solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a query is successful doesn't mean it has the data in it, 0 rows can still be a successfully executed query.